# C# 11: "field" keyword not supported in VS 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-11.0

I have a .NET 7.0 WinForms project which claims, in its properties, to have the Language version set to 11.0 (and I've played in the .csproj to make it "latest" and "preview", etc.).

ReSharper's inspections suggest that I can use the `field` keyword in a number of places, but when I do so, VS hates the refactored result and I get compile errors ("The name 'field' does not exist in the current context", etc.).

I am completely at a loss as to why my VS (I've even tried the preview -- I'm on Professional 2022 version 17.5.0 preview 6.0) doesn't want to like C# 11.

Here's what I have for installed SDKs, in case that plays into things...

```
C:\>dotnet --list-sdks
7.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.200-preview.22628.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Here is one of the areas of code that is producing the error.

**BEFORE**

```cs
private int _updateDepth; // this is "grayed" by R# with hint to address

private int UpdateDepth
{
    get => _updateDepth;
    set
    {
        _updateDepth = value;
        if (!SkipHandlers && !SkipCallbacks && UpdateDepth is 0)
            RunGameDataChangedCallback();
    }
}
```

**AFTER**

```cs
private int UpdateDepth
{
    get;
    set
    {
        field = value;
        if (!SkipHandlers && !SkipCallbacks && UpdateDepth is 0)
            RunGameDataChangedCallback();
    }
}
```

I have also tried (because in reading about the field keyword, it seems to say that the property must be initialized) to add  `= 0;` after the final closing curly-bracket, but that doesn't help.

**COMPILER ERRORS**

```
CS0501  'GameControl.UpdateDepth.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
CS0103  The name 'field' does not exist in the current context
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the code that's producing the error message.

Comment: Hello, @ewerspej - I have updated my question to include the code and the error; thank you for the request!

Comment: Why do you think this should compile? [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/84Jmkx)

Comment: Hi @GuruStron - I believe it should compile for two reasons.  First, according to this page (and others) https://dev.to/bytehide/leaked-c-11-features-the-best-christmas-gift-from-microsoft-pn1 the field keyword was released in C#11 last November.  Secondly, ReSharper's applied refactoring, I don't think, would happen, if it didn't expect the result to compile (and correspondingly its advice "Replace with 'field' keyword", be advice to do something that won't compile).  Am I (and JetBrains?) somehow mistaken that the field keyword is available in C#11?

Comment: There is no such keyword in [C# keywords list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/) and there is no mention of it in [C# 11 What's New article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11)

Comment: [This page listing C# 11 changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11) doesn't say anything about this construct. Also the article you referenced says "but it **seems that they are convinced** that in C# 11 it will be released", doesn't sound definitive to me.

Comment: Thanks, @GuruStron and rshepp - So it seems perhaps JetBrains got fooled too, and jumped the gun?  I am curious -- if either of you (or others) have ReSharper installed (and/or use Rider), are you also seeing the same "use the field keyword" advice show up when you ask for code inspection?

Comment: I would not trust Visual Studio. What does `dotnet build` return?

Comment: @ManusHand I have latest version of Rider and it does not provide such suggestion. Check if your R# plugin is latest stable version.

Comment: Interestingly, @GuruStron, I, too, use Rider and it also does NOT provide that suggestion.  Very odd that (the latest, also) R# in VS does, though, as I thought that was lockstep with Rider.  Learn something new every day.

Comment: Hi @beautifulcoder - You had my hopes up, but `dotnet build` also spits out the same two compiler errors.  :-(

Comment: Bah, then sounds like it's not supported yet. I deleted my answer.

Comment: Here's an answer, it's simply not in C# 11 and may (or may not) only make it into C# 12: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/140#issuecomment-1209670376

Comment: This is about the new features of C#11, if the time is reorganized, you can refer to it in detail. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11

Answer (score 7):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/140#issuecomment-1209670376) from the C# GitHub repository, there have been issues with the implementation of the `field` keyword and so it didn't make it into C# 11. It may (or may not) come in C# 12.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is R# bug (so I suggest reporting it or try checking if there are updates present). ATM there is no `field` keyword present in C# ([keywords list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/)) and such feature is not listed among released with C# 11 and .NET 7 ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11)) because it was removed from the release ([github discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/140#issuecomment-1209645505)).

Answer (score 1):

Consensus (and Microsoft) seems to say that despite pages saying so, and despite JetBrains ReSharper thinking so, the `field` keyword is not supported in C# 11 after all.

I have submitted a bug report to JetBrains telling them that they might want to not give bad advice.  Anyone interested in this can follow the request at https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/4782760

Thanks to all!

Comment: This is a proposed feature which may be in C# 12.
https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/140